I need to change the logo of the token created by you
Dear representatives of your ecosystem,
With respect, I would like to inform you about a small discrepancy regarding the logo of the currency that I have created within your ecosystem. Due to an error, the current logo needs to be either deleted or replaced. Considering the importance and impact that this logo has on the representation of the currency, I kindly request your assistance in resolving this issue.
I would like to emphasize that I am the owner of the token and I want to ensure that the associated image accurately reflects the identity of the currency.
The address of my token is: 5iR95r5T2SmddZgwTqUX4EA88Jz4EWQHKuYyGzWh7Xv6.
The token is immutable
Please guide me in this situation and help me resolve the issue regarding the logo of my currency.
Thank you in advance for your support.
Sincerely,
Owner LeuCoin România  (LEU)
